# How to redirect without Google following it?

Tags: google-search, googlebot

*I originally asked this on StackOverflow, but got told to move it here, so here I am.*

I'm running a host and want to redirect visitors to a page on my main site if the client hasn't set up any content yet. Now, since I don't want that Google and co think that my site content has something to do with my clients side content.

In short, I'm looking for sort of a `nofollow`, but for redirects.

Any thoughts?

Note: I want to keep the placeholder file as easy to remove as possible, so it'd be great if there would be a solution that involves just one file.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, a `302 Temporary` redirect could be useful here. However, keep in mind that Google doesn't generally associate your site with everyone  else who redirects their site to yours, because in general you have no control over who redirects to you.

Comment: Regardless of Google/search engines, if you are intending to externally redirect the user, you would need to implement a 302 (or 307) anyway, as opposed to a 301 (or 308), otherwise, users will cache the redirect and not see any _new_ client content should they revisit the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 307 Temporary Redirect is the most appropriate one to use in this situation. It tells search engines that the new location is only temporary and will change in the future.

However, it doesn't work precisely as a nofollow, but it's the closest.

I'm guessing your client wants to put something like "under construction" pages or something along those lines, and you want to redirect those.

It's always best to only put a page up if it's going to have some content on it. Creating pages only to redirect them away is generally a terrible practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a default.html (or whatever your default index file is called) in the client's web root directory.

Then in `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` you tweak the `DirectoryIndex` value and put a list of file names in the order in which they should be used.

If you have the order of preference for default files be `index.php` and then `default.html` (or similar), your holding page will be served if nothing else is there.  But if they install wordpress or anything that uses `index.php`, then that will over-ride and will be displayed first.

The naming convention and default order may need to be adjusted, but it will solve your problem.

FWIW, the line in my http.conf is `DirectoryIndex index.php index.php7 index.php5 index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.jp index.phtml index.shtml index.xhtml index.html index.htm index.js index.htm default.html`

Note default.html is last, all those other files would load first.

If you use WHM/cpanel you can  do this in `WHM` > `Apache configuration` > `DirectoryIndex Priority` which will update your `httpd.conf` for you.

Bonus tip: you can add your custom default.html holding page to the cpanel skeleton directory and when an account is created, it will automatically copy whatever files are in that directory to the new account's web root directory.

Comment: So instead of redirecting, they should set up default files for every client?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Assuming cpanel, it is trivial.  Create an account and the skeleton files are automatically copied to their home directory.  If the DirectoryIndex of the holding page file is low enough, any other index file will over-ride it.